# PHP Multidimensional Array loop and group by value

Tags: php, arrays, loops, multidimensional-array

I have a multidimensional array that looks like this:

```
Array ( 
 [0] => Array ( [A] => Apple ) 
 [1] => Array ( [A] => Banana ) 
 [2] => Array ( [A] => Strawberry ) 
 [3] => Array ( [B] => Computer ) 
)
```

Now i would like to loop through that array and output the values grouped by [A],[B], …
But in my case I don’t know if there is an [A], [B] or [C].

The Result should look like this:

```
[A] Apple, Banana, Strawberry
[B] Computer
```

This is my code so far:

```
$service_links[] = array();
$sl_i = 0;

if( have_rows('services') ):

// loop through the rows of data
while ( have_rows('services') ) : the_row();

    if( get_row_layout() == 'service_category' ) {

        $service_category_taxonomy = get_sub_field('service_category_taxonomy');
        $service_links[$sl_i][$service_category_taxonomy] = get_sub_field('service_group_title');

        $sl_i++;
    }

endwhile;

endif;

foreach ( $service_links as $var ) {
   echo " ????? ";
}
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: This is a fairly trivial programming exercise. Can you show us what you have so far?

Comment: Sorry, I’m just starting to learn php.

Comment: so what if you use array_key_exists() link: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would loop it with a `foreach`:

```
$array = ''; //<-- This is your array

$final = [];
foreach ($array as $a) {
    foreach ($a as $k => $v) {
        $final[$k][] = $v;
    }
}
var_dump($final);
```

**Result:**

```
array (size=2)
  'A' => 
    array (size=3)
      0 => string 'Apple' (length=5)
      1 => string 'Banana' (length=6)
      2 => string 'Strawberry' (length=10)
  'B' => 
    array (size=1)
      0 => string 'Computer' (length=8)
```

You can later use `implode` to make your results comma delimited:

```
echo implode(',', $final['A']); // OUTPUT: Apple,Banana,Strawberry
```

Comment: Hey CodeGodie, thanks’s a lot. This is was a great help!

Answer (score 1):

Something like this :

```
$results = array();
    foreach($arr as $a){
    foreach($a as $key=>$value){
        if(array_key_exists($key,$results)){
            $results[$key]=$results[$key].",".$value;
        }else{
            $results[$key] = $value;
        }
    }
    }
```